# Rotating Conductor Loop

Tags: pstricks, animate

I would like to animate a rotating conductor loop with pstricks. So far, it works as it's supposed to be, but there is one problem. When RotX=30 or RotX= 210 (4th and 22nd frame), the conductor loop is drawn in the opposite direction. Compile with latex->dvips->ps4pdf to see.

I tried different viewing points. Alpha=90 and Beta=90 seems to be no problem ... But thats not the intended point of view ... Why doesn't it work with only these two angles?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-3dplot}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}

\begin{animateinline}[begin={\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-5,-5)(5,5)},end={\end{pspicture}},controls,loop]{8}
\multiframe{37}{nB=0+10}{
%Winkel
\psset{Beta=20,Alpha=55}
%Koordinatensystem
\pstThreeDCoor[xMin=0,xMax=5,yMin=0,yMax=5,zMin=0,zMax=5,IIIDticks]
%Line
\pstThreeDLine[RotX=\nB,linecolor=darkgray!40,linewidth=4pt,linearc=2pt](4,0.5,0)(3,0.5,0)(3,2,0)(-3,2,0)(-3,-2,0)(3,-2,0)(3,-0.5,0)(4,-0.5,0)
}
\end{animateinline}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have no real idea what's going wrong here. I tried `\psset{Beta=20,Alpha=11}` and `\multiframe{35}{nB=0+11}{` which gives an acceptable result.